# Get the current script path from MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I'm writing JavaScript code for MongoDB shell in client. How can I get the path of the script file which is executing? Please note it's not the value of `pwd()`. For example, I'm executing `/my_scripts/utils.js` from `/my_path`:

```
> mongodb --nodb /my_scripts/utils.js
```

so `pwd()` returns `/my_path`, but how can I get the full path (or relative path to the value of `pwd()`) of the current executing file, which is `/my_scripts/utils.js`?

Comment: You're not really being clear. Are you trying to get the full path of the utils.js to use it inside that script? Or you want to find the full path of all scripts that are currently running?

Comment: Can we execute multiple scripts at the same time? I need to get `/my_scripts/utils.js` from `utils.js`. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 2):

in case you are still wondering, you can call pwd() from inside your script to get the path where your script

More information about pwd() can be found in the MongoDb manual: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/pwd

Comment: For me, pwd() does not return the path where the script is running e.g. /home/mysername/scripts. It just returns the home directory e.g. /home/mysername/. And load('./myfile.js') seems to be relative to the home directory, not the actual location of the script. So I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: I think that's the link you need - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.2/reference/method/pwd/
Or maybe event better (because it's deprecated) try this one - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.2/reference/method/js-native/#std-label-native-in-mongosh and search for pwd() in the doc

Answer (score 0):

you can try `bash shell/a.sh`,write `pwd` command into file `a.sh`

Answer (score 0):

you can run your utils.js from a shell script.

usage:

./run.sh path_to_utils.js

```
run.sh

#!/bin/sh

// $1 is path_to_utils.js
echo $1

mongo < $1
```

e.g:

```
./run.sh ~/Downloads/t.js
/Users/sunus/Downloads/t.js
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.2
connecting to: test
Hello
bye
```

Comment: That's kinda workaround - so the mongo shell doesn't support that?